# How to make Android application support all device screen?

Tags: android, screen, ui-design

Am android beginners, am developing small size application, that application UI design and function change to each device screen, i don't know that various, my application UI design and function  fit all android device screen.

Answer (score -1):

hi you should you layout for design your app.
you can see all screen preview for your appp.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

see this link for more information

Answer (score -1):

in your res folder, you can put different view for different screen size like this : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In your res folder, you can have this :

- drawable-large-land (For Large screen in landscape)
- drawable large-port (For Large screen in portrait)
- drawable-xlarge-land (The same thing for XLarge Screen)
- etc...

You have the value of each screen size in the link before!

Answer (score -1):

Since Android 1.6 (API Level 4), Android provides support for multiple screen sizes and densities.

So in your resources you provide different layouts for different screen sizes.
The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are `small`, `normal`, `large`, and `xlarge`. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in `layout-xlarge/`.

You should also provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities. You can use for density-specific resources are `ldpi` (low), `mdpi` (medium), `hdpi` (high), `xhdpi` extra-high), `xxhdpi` (extra-extra-high), and `xxxhdpi` (extra-extra-extra-high). For example, bitmaps for high-density screens should go in `drawable-hdpi/`.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html